# Coarse-resolution subsampling of time-series data

Tags: time-series, references

Suppose I have time series data with a very fine resolution, e.g. 100 datapoints per second.  I want to report this data to some service that can only take data at 1 point per second.  I need to do something with those 100 datapoints and only report 1.  I could pick one at random, pick the first, pick the last, report the mean, alternate between reporting the 80th percentile and 20th percentile, etc.

What sort of statistics associated with a time series data tend to be important to preserve when resampling/subsampling?  What techniques for subsampling do a good job of preserving said statistics?

Sorry for the open-ended and somewhat subjective nature of this question, any guidance, industry standards, or reference papers would be appreciated.

EDIT: For the context I'm interested, the raw metrics from the source are coming from a server in a cluster.  Metrics will include things like current heap memory usage or disk usage in MB, number of subprocesses currently running, and time taken to perform a certain type of task we want to monitor.

Comment: Could you be more specific with respect to what kind of data you have? E.g. you may want to treat stock variables differently from flow variables. Is it economic, biological, still other time series?